# How to loop through all the rows of a gridview in all pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using vb.net and I have a gridview which contains four columns including Textbox as a Itemtemplate field. This gridview is containing information of students and the textbox is the attendance status of the students for everytday. So, the requirement is to take the input from all of the textbox existing in the gridview as an input of student attendance for each student. Here, Paging is enabled because number or students can be more than 80 sometimes. But the problem is when I am looping through the gridview rows to get the textbox input it is only taking the first page values and the rest are left. I really need help on this. Any help is appreciated.

This is the GridView Code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        CellPadding="4" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="20">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="crkod" HeaderText="Student ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="crnama" HeaderText="Student Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attendance Status" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAttend" runat="server" BackColor="Control" MaxLength="1" 
                        Width="12px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind of Save Button:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To Me.GridView1.PageCount - 1
        Me.GridView1.PageIndex = k

        Dim rowNum As Integer = Me.GridView1.Rows.Count

        For i As Integer = 0 To rowNum - 1
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("txtAttend"), TextBox)
            attendSts = tb.Text


            studntID = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text


            Sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (studentID,attendStatus,attendDate,courseID,yearsem,monthsem)" _
            & " VALUES (" _
             & "'" & studntID & "'," _
             & "'" & attendSts & "'," _
             & "'" & attnDate & "'," _
             & "'" & courseCode & "'," _
             & yearsem & "," _
             & monthsem & ")"

            CreateCommand(Sql, strConn)
        Next
    Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try binding your gridview after each page loop

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but still the same. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Commands Below which I'm using it in my projects. Its logic is so simple, you go through all pages and in every page you go through all rows. You can also get your current page before doing this and after looping all you can get back there ;)

```
//Get Current Page Index so You can get back here after commands
                int a = GridView1.PageIndex;
    //Loop through All Pages
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.PageCount; i++)
                {
    //Set Page Index
                    GridView1.SetPageIndex(i);
    //After Setting Page Index Loop through its Rows
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        //Do Your Commands Here
                    }
                }
    //Getting Back to the First State
                GridView1.SetPageIndex(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never-ever (and this is a popular issue with new programmers) try to work with the data in the grid directly (ok almost never).  You should work with the data you bound the grid to.  This is the thing you set as the `GridView1.Datasource = ?` most likely in your page_load or some DataBinding event.

Assuming this is a datatable, you would want to do something like this:

```
For each dr as datarow in ctype(GridView1.Datasource,DataTable).Rows
  attendSts = dr("Attend")
  studntID = dr("studntID")
  ..Your insert code here
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer. But can you please make me a little bit more clear how I can get the user input in the template field text box inside the grid. I am quite new in this so I really need help on this. Thank you.